# an infinite system of infinite products

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

we have the sequence of positive real numbers ${a_{j}}$ , such that :
$$ \frac{1}{j+1}<a_{j}<\frac{1}{j} \;\;\;\;,\;j\geqslant 1$$
and we have, for every integer $n\geqslant 1$, the equality :

$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{a_{j}^{2}}{(a_{j}n+a_{j}-1)^{2}}\right)$$
furthermore, the infinite product :
$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{j})e^{-a_{j}}$$
is convergent. in fact, there is an entire function defined as:
$$f(x)=C\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1+xa_{j})e^{-xa_{j}}$$
such that, at negative integers:
$$f(-n)=K(-1)^{n}n!$$
$C$ and $K$ being constants.
can we prove that such a sequence exists ? how can we solve for the numbers $a_{j}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If we define $b_j=1/{a_j}$ then we have $j<b_j<j+1$ for $j \geq{1}$ and the product becomes
$$A=\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2-b_j)(n-b_j)}{(n+1-b_j)^2}.$$
I guess the idea is to consider the finite product for $j=1,\cdots,m$ say and cancel out as many terms as possible. That can be achieved if
$$b_j=b_{j-1}+1, j=2,3,\cdots$$
but since none of the $b_j$ is an integer, no factor is of the form  $n$ plus an integer. Instead we get
$$A=\frac{n+2-b_1}{n+1-b_1}$$
Are you sure you wrote everything down correctly?